# Definition of vector bundles - what is meant by a structure of a real vector space?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

I am currently reading John Lee's book about Differential geometry and I don't fully understand his definition of vector bundles. Unfortunately, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle) didn't help.

A vector bundle of rank $k$ is a continuous map $\pi\colon E\to M$ with the following property (among others):

> *For each $p\in M$, $\pi^{-1}(p)$ is endowed with the structure
> of a $k$-dimensional real vector space.*

On page 13 of "Introduction to
Smooth Manifolds", he defines a smooth structure to be a smooth atlas, so I thought that a structure might be an atlas. But even is if this is true, I don't see what he means by the addition "of a $k$-dimensional real vector space".

Comment: Think of the tangent bundle of a manifold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's structure in the general mathematical sense of "adding something" to a set to get a richer object:

- To endow a set $G$ with a group structure is to pair it with an operation $*$ such that $(G,*)$ is a group;
- To endow a set $V$ with a vector space structure is to pair it with operations $+, \cdot$ satisfying the vector space axioms;
- To endow a set $M$ with a smooth structure is to pair it with a smooth atlas.

In this case, what is meant is that *part of the definition* of a vector bundle is the choice of a $k$-dimensional vector space structure on each fiber $\pi^{-1}(p),$ i.e. $+$ and $\cdot$ satisfying the vector space axioms are defined on each $\pi^{-1}(p).$